# JDBC to the limit

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm using `java.sql.Connection.setAutoCommit(false)` and `java.sql.PreparedStatement.addBatch()` to do some bulk inserts. I'm guessing how many correct insert/update statements can be safely executed before a commit? For example, executing 100.000 inserts before a commit may results in a JDBC driver complaint or memory leakage or something else? I guess there is a limit about how many statements I can execute before a commit, where can I find such infos?

Comment: Can't you benchmark this? It will depend on a) your data b) the database etc.etc.

Comment: It depends on how large each statement is. If you only have 5 integer columns, then you probably won't get a problem. If you have 100 columns with `varchar(1000)` then things will look differently. It also depends on the DBMS being used. Some are faster if you only commit **once**, others are faster if you commit frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's **no** limit on the number of `DML` statements. Every `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` you push to the database is actually tracked in the database only. So there would not be any memory leakage like you mentioned. Memory leakage in `JDBC` can usually be related with the unclosed result sets or prepared statements only.

But other side, So much of `DML` operations without `COMMIT`, could do so much of logging in the DB. And this might impact the performance of other operations. When you issue a `COMMIT` after say *millions* of `INSERTs`, the other operations like `INDEX` analysis, data replication (if any) would put more overhead to the `DBMS`. Still these points are completely `DBMS` specific. `JDBC` driver has nothing to with.

Comment: That is not true. When using batched statements **all** the statements (actually the _values_ for the statements) added via `addBatch()` are kept in memory by the driver until `executeBatch()` is called.

Comment: In DB2 I got *java.sql.SQLException: Limit on number of statements exceeded.*

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes I agree they are in the driver. But they are just statements(text), should not create a overhead to the `JVM` perhaps?! And if at all any limit would be a `DBMS` parameter(customized by DBA?) only.

Comment: If you keep the data for 100.000 rows in memory, it sure will have some "overhead".